# boost serialize

Tags: boost, serialize

При намеренной порче файла (например, удаление строки), откуда boost::serialize загружает значения, происходит следующее: значение испорченного объекта равно значеню следующего объекта, который шел в файле после испорченного. Почему так работает boost?

Comment: Потому что так решил(и) разработчик(и) этого модуля.